# one account have many friend who have same attribute of user ? how to implement it in DB & how it look like in ER diagram

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many, entity-relationship, self-reference

one account have many friend who have same attribute of user ? how to implement it in DB & how it look like in ER diagram

i'm trying to build simple DB project where i have

> user with (email,password)

each user have many friend where the friend also a user !

user should able to Request another user as friend and accept or reject that

and if user1 friend to user2 must the opp work user2 friend of user1

??
what tables i need ? and what the relation ?   how it look in ER diagram

how it work i'm not Expert i looked to another Q but not clear to me  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your question you need 2 tables: Users and UserConnections where User table has the basic attributes (userid, email, password) of the user.  UserConnections has RequesterUserID, TargetedUserID, and results of that request (i.e. did the user accept or reject the request).

When you write your SQL you can join the userid table back to itself thru the UserConnections table to obtain the information you need.

This is quick, sample code only to give the basic idea.  I am creating the two tables and inserting some sample data, with one query to show you how to obtain some data from it.  Do not use this actual code, it is for idea only.  The most important concept is that the useraccount table is used twice in the query, each with a different alias.  The r alias represents the requestor user, and the t alias represents the targeted user.  The UserConnections is a form of a Cross Reference table and allows a many to many join from user account back to itself.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAccount](
[UserID] [varchar](20) Not NULL,
[EMail] [varchar](20) Not NULL,
[FullName] [varchar](30) Not NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserConnections](
    [RUserID] [varchar](20) Not NULL,
    [TUserID] [varchar](20) Not NULL,
    [results] [varchar](10) Not NULL
) ON 

[PRIMARY]



insert useraccount select 'user1', 'user1_email', 'user1_name'
insert useraccount select 'user2', 'user2_email', 'user2_name'
insert useraccount select 'user3', 'user3_email', 'user3_name'
insert useraccount select 'user4', 'user4_email', 'user4_name'
insert useraccount select 'user5', 'user5_email', 'user5_name'


insert UserConnections select 'user1', 'user2', 'ACCEPTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user1', 'user3', 'ACCEPTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user1', 'user4', 'REJECTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user1', 'user5', 'REJECTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user2', 'user3', 'REJECTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user2', 'user4', 'ACCEPTED'
insert UserConnections select 'user5', 'user3', 'REJECTED'

--if you wanted to get all the rejected requests for a particular user
select c.tuserid as 'reject_user_id',  t.fullname as 'reject_user_name'  from useraccount r join UserConnections  c 
on r.userid = c.ruserid
join useraccount t on c.tuserid = t.userid
  and c.results  = 'REJECTED' 
where r.userid = 'user1'
```

**results:**
user4   user4_name
user5   user5_name

Comment: "...  request (i.e. did the user accept or reject the request).

When you write your SQL you can join the userid table back to itself thru the UserConnections table to obtain the information you need."

how it look in sql pls :) and where the friend list will be

Comment: thank u ! another Q the relation   user account and the  userConn... its m:N or 1:N

Comment: one to many.  UserAccount table can have 1 row per user.   That user can show up many times in the UserConnecton table, based on the people that user has tried to connect to and based on how many users tried connecting to that user.

Comment: again thank u a lot ! , after user accept that request should i keep it in same table or who accepts i add him in other table called user_friend and how i achieve if user.1 friend to user.2 i want make sql to make user.2 friend to user.1 ؟  what he relation between account user with account user is it like employ and supervision or no relation ! i can't Attach  my imagine of ER digram can u explain it

Comment: Thanks for checking off question as answered.  There is only so much we can take this via StackOverflow, but on the UserConnect table the results (or status would be a better name) column indicates the friend request status. (pending, accepted, rejected, etc.)  you would also have a datetime column, probably one for the request datetime, and one for the response datetime.  also, status description would be in a ref table, only the keys in the UserConnect table.   There is no 100% right way to do this but you can do most of it with the 2 tables, you don't need to have user_friend table

Comment: ohh another Q came ! u know when u send the request i can get the result At the same time ! What you suggest

Comment: re ERD you just need to look up an example, google images of ERDs and you will find plenty of examples.    Re your next question, not sure what you mean.

Comment: when user.1 request user.2 While awaiting a response how i can mange the result of that  request !? i think to  add value "Under Processor"  .

Comment: when i have situation
user.1 , user.2 accepted 

i want SQL to make the opp of it 

> user.2 , user.1.accepted to